# How is WSO2 API manager perform OAuth2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO API manager and have basic idea of oAuth 2.0.
I want to secure my API through key manager of WSO2. For this i followed following steps:

1. Created user "**dilip**" using carbon admin and provided him publisher access.
2. Created and published one API say "**Weather API**" with oAuth security in publisher portal using user "**dilip**"
3. Created another user say "**Sandeep**" In developer portal and granted him internal subscriber access.
4. "**Sandeep**" logs in developer portal and created one Application say "**APP_Sandeep**" and Subscribed "**Weather API**"
5. Generate Client ID and Client secret for application "**APP_Sandeep**".

In OAuth terminology there are few actors like

1. Resource Server(e.g Gmail)
2. Resource Owner( user)
3. Third party Application/client( e.g printing service)

*Now my question is that in the scenario explained above w.r.t WSO2 who are following*?

1. Resource Server
2. Resource owner
3. Resource itself
4. Client

I assume following :
1.Resource Server is WSO2 API manager
2. Resource of owner is "**dilip**"
3. Resource is "**Weather API**"
4. Client is "**APP_Sandeep**"

But I am not confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct with respect to WSO2 API Manager.

- Resource Server - The server hosting the protected resources, capable of accepting and responding to protected resource requests using access tokens. In your scenario, it is the `WSO2 API Manager`
- Resource owner - An entity capable of granting access to a protected resource. In your scenario, it is `Dilip`
- Resource itself - In your scenario, it is the `Weather API`
- Client - An application making protected resource requests. In your scenario, it is `APP_Sandeep`

The explanations were extracted from this [Say Hello to OAuth 2.0](https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2019/10/say-hello-to-oauth-2.0/). You can refer it for more understanding